# Was the Battle of Khaibar was pre emptive?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, salawat, seerah

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

I was reading the conquest of Khaibar and although Alhamdulillah I don't doubt the decision taken by our Holy Prophet Muhammed (saw) , I do feel a bit uncomfortable at the fact that the conquest was mostly a pre emptive strike.

The People (Jews) of Khaibar surely were treacherous and a threat but we're not openly engaged in a war with the Muslim.

Are the reports of Ibn Ishaq or other writers trustworthy regarding this?

Were conquests like these considered the "norm" back then?

Answer (score 1):

As Far As I know , the Jews of Khaibar were involved in the *battle of Al Ahzab* also known as the battle of the Trench , which was so intense that the Muslims were almost wiped out from their home base in Medina , and here I don't mean the Jewish residents of Medina , whom openly betrayed the prophet and were severely punished for it , but the attacking parties themselves , so Technically they were in open war with the prophet , maybe not exactly at the time of the battle of Khaibar, but the prophet didn't let their participation slide .
However , during the Rashidun Caliphate many wars were pre-emptive actually , so it isn't uncommon in Islamic history post the Prophet (PBUH).
References :

- [Battle of Al Ahzab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Trench)
- [Khalid Ibn Al Waleed's preemptive wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khalid_ibn_al-Walid)